# Executing HMSET command with hiredis

Tags: c++, redis, hiredis

I want to put a `std::map<std::string, std::string>` into redis server with hiredis. Since the [API only allows formatted strings](https://github.com/redis/hiredis) to be passed to `redisCommand`, I'm unable to store the map via a single command. I've tried using pipelines, but that is slower than `HMSET` and is therefore not applicable to performance restrains I'm in.

Anyone knows of any direct or indirect methods to pass a variant sized map via hiredis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are supposed to use the "Argv" flavors of redisCommand:

```
int redisAppendCommandArgv(redisContext *c, int argc, const char **argv, const size_t *argvlen);
void *redisCommandArgv(redisContext *c, int argc, const char **argv, const size_t *argvlen);
```

You need to build two arrays (pointers and sizes) before they can be called.

Something like this should work (untested):

```
void hmset( redisContext *c, const string &key, const map<string,string> &m )
{
  vector<const char *> argv;
  vector<size_t> argvlen;

  static char cmd[] = "HMSET";
  argv.push_back( cmd );
  argvlen.push_back( sizeof(cmd)-1 );

  argv.push_back( key.c_str() );
  argvlen.push_back( key.size() );

  map<string,string>::const_iterator i;
  for ( i=m.begin(); i!=m.end(); ++i )
  {
    argv.push_back( i->first.c_str() );
    argvlen.push_back( i->first.size() );
    argv.push_back( i->second.c_str() );
    argvlen.push_back( i->second.size() );
  }

  void *r = redisCommandArgv(c, argv.size(), &(argv[0]), &(argvlen[0]) );
  if ( !r )
    throw runtime_error( "Redis error" );
  freeReplyObject( r );
}
```

Note that if your map contains a lot of items, it is a wrong idea to push it to Redis in one single command. Past N=100-1000 items, variadic commands should be split (in batches of N items) and pipelined. Keep in mind that Redis is single-threaded. When a huge command is executed, nothing else is executed. Plus, you can hit the limit of the communication buffer.

Comment: That's it. I recommend everyone who gets to this answer; to double check notes mentioned at the end of answer since they are as important as the answer itself.

Comment: I tried it and can confirm that your solution works out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

This is a late answer, however, with [redis-plus-plus](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus) you can easily put a `std::map<std::string, std::string>` into Redis.

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of this Redis client library. If you have any problem with this client, feel free to [let me know](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus/issues). If you like it, also feel free to [star it](https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus) :)

Sample Code:

```
Redis redis("tcp://127.0.0.1:6379");
std::map<std::string, std::string> m = {std::make_pair("k1", "v1"), std::make_pair("k2", "v2")};
redis.hmset("hash-key", m.begin(), m.end());
```

Check the doc for detail.